# Why "df -h' does not display mount point /home?

Tags: linux, partition, partition-table

Created 3 partitions for Linux(with dual boot): `sda5` `sda6` and `sda7`

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    718847    716800   350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          718848 163842047 163123200  77.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       163844094 625137344 461293251   220G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       300913578 574355879 273442302 130.4G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       574355943 625137344  50781402  24.2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       163844096 300912639 137068544  65.4G 83 Linux


$ lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL           UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                  
├─sda1 ntfs     System Reserved C20A88200A881417                     
├─sda2 ntfs                     DEDA9BDBDA9BADF1                     
├─sda4                                                               
├─sda5 ext3                     5420f841-c31f-469e-8ccc-2234a78ac629 
├─sda6 swap                     c8b4b405-868d-44a4-877b-3041eed61974 [SWAP]
└─sda7 ext4                     b3f61b80-d200-40c0-9cfd-f5547ecb8e68 /
sr0                                                                  
loop0  squashfs                                                      /snap/code/7
loop1  squashfs                                                      /snap/core/6964
```

---

During partitioning with Ubuntu CD,

mount point to `sda7` is given as `/`

mount point to `sda5` is given as `/home`

---

But below command does not show `/home` mount point:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           789M  9.5M  780M   2% /run
/dev/sda7        65G  7.5G   54G  13% /
tmpfs           3.9G  130M  3.8G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/6964
/dev/loop0      127M  127M     0 100% /snap/code/7
tmpfs           789M   56K  789M   1% /run/user/1000
```

---

Why `df -h` does not display `/home` mount point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your /dev/sda5 partition is not mounted at all based on the outputs given from `df -h`.

Remember, the df command only shows the partitions which have been mounted (excluding swap partitions). If your partition is not mounted it will not show when you type the df command.

As you can see from the command you typed, `df -h`, that only sda7 is showing, but sda5 and sda6 are not because one of them is a swap and the other is not even mounted -- hence it doesn't show when df -h is used.

To mount the dev/sda5 partition you can use the `mount` command and mount it to the directory of your choice. Example:

```
mount /dev/sda5 /home/bob
```

This will mount the sda5 partition into the home directory of the user 'bob'.

Once this is done, the df command will now show the /home mount point for the /dev/sda5 partition.

**FSTAB**

For a persistent mount where partitions will be mounted automatically upon boot, you need to edit the /etc/fstab file.
You need to add it to /etc/fstab use your favourite text editor.

**Be careful with this file as it can quite easily cause your system not to boot.**

---

```
#device      mountpoint             fstype    options  dump    fsck

/dev/sdb1    /home/yourname/mydata    ext4    defaults    0    1
```

---

Comment: 1) If I run this mount command, does the existing files of `/home/username` get purged? 2) It should get mount on every start, what entry is needed to add in `/etc/fstab` for permanent changes?

Comment: No not at all, all mounting does is attaches the partition with the file system of the host operating system so it can be accessed and used

Comment: But where does it store the mapping entry of `/dev/sda5` with mount point `/home/username`? so that every restart of OS can take care of this mount... because I don't see any entry for this in `/etc/fstab`

Comment: I will edit my answer to add some detail on fstab

Comment: But am unable to create a file or directory after mount....

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: After I run mount command(`mount /dev/sda5 /home/bob`), `sudo touch file` works but `touch file` does not work in `/home/bob`

Comment: Type 'sudo /dev/sda5 /mnt'

Comment: not a valid command

Comment: After mount the owner of the directory is changed to `root`

Comment: Switch the user to root and type 'chown yourusername:yourusername /mount/directory/name'

Comment: yes I did that... but as sudoer...Ubuntu CD did not ask for root passwd... so i do not know root passwd

Comment: Then whats the problem?

Comment: You don't need root password to use `sudo` . You use your own. The installer should have given the primary user permission to use sudo. The command is with out the quotes @qasim used the wrong quotes to mark the code as code (markdown), ignore them.

Comment: Yes i used the wrong quotes im not very familiar with the answer layout

Comment: One would usually do `mount /dev/sda5 /home` then create folders inside for each user.